Crackling sounds sound on Ubuntu 24.04 lts
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 on my mac mini late 2014 (with lspci i get two sound device, the Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller and the Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller), I am experiencing a very annoying crackling sound every time I open any content with audio, but only on my hdmi channel, my headphones works just fine and so do my internal speakers. I've tried some solutions for older version but none worked out. for context i previously had the 23.10 version without this kind of issue.

This may be a stupid suggestion, but have you tried a different cable?

yeah i tried but it change nothing

Ditto. Also using Mac Mini 2014 and sound via hdmi is crackling continuously.

Did you find a fix for this? I tried a wipe and clean install but no change.

I've also tried a clean install and nothing, I'm using my internal speaker and the headphones, not being able to find a solution I'm hoping that someone answer to this post or that some random update fix the problem by chance.

Same problem, same 2014 Mac mini and no solution yet either. If you go in Settings, Sound output, Configuration, and it's currently set to Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output, see if you have the option to change it to Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output. It helps quite a bit. Crackling doesn't go away entirely, but it's at least listenable.

I had the same problem with my Linux Mint 22 and kernel 6.8.0-47-generic.
I reduced the cracking by

Creating the file /etc/modprobe.d/mysound.conf
Adding the line
`options snd_intel_dspcfg dsp_driver=3
reboot

Sound still crackles about every 2 minutes, but not as loud as before.
Source.
